# Transferring Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

i bought a new macbook pro with mountain lion preinstalled and i dont know how to put it on my older 10.6.8 Imac. There is no file for it on the macbook and says i havent bought it in the app store.

Answer (score 5):

You can only share it if you bought it from the App Store.  Pre-installed versions are single-copy licenses:

> A. Preinstalled and Single-Copy Apple Software License. Subject to the
>   terms and conditions of this License, unless you obtained the Apple
>   Software from the Mac App Store or under a volume license, maintenance
>   or other written agreement from Apple, you are granted a limited, non-
>   exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple
>   Software on a single Apple- branded computer at any one time. For
>   example, these single-copy license terms apply to you if you obtained
>   the Apple Software preinstalled on Apple-branded hardware.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4971852?start=0&tstart=0